# uploading to S3: PermanentRedirect

Tags: amazon-web-services, next.js

This error is coming when file uploading:

```
Error uploading to S3: PermanentRedirect: The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint.

les/next/dist/server/lib/start-server.js:140:13) {
  '$fault': 'client',
  '$metadata': {
    httpStatusCode: 301,
    requestId: '15FT2CFREYE2RZH4',
    extendedRequestId: 'bHgMekr6oM5JHOG2lrbV0hK//YMVz87yujbVeJx1Na4CbD7jFcCHPKgfinsbMRjOnIxVZHC0puE=',
    cfId: undefined,
    attempts: 1,
    totalRetryDelay: 0
  },
  Code: 'PermanentRedirect',
  Endpoint: 'doctors-kitchen.s3.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com',
  Bucket: 'doctors-kitchen',
  RequestId: '15FT2CFREYE2RZH4',
  HostId: 'bHgMekr6oM5JHOG2lrbV0hK//YMVz87yujbVeJx1Na4CbD7jFcCHPKgfinsbMRjOnIxVZHC0puE='
}
```

This is my route:

```
import { PutObjectCommand, S3Client } from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";
import { buffer } from "stream/consumers";
import uniqid from "uniqid";

export async function POST(req) {
  const data = await req.formData();
  if (data.get("file")) {
    console.log("we have file", data.get("file"));
    const file = data.get("file");
    const s3Client = new S3Client({
      region: "ap-south-1",
      credentials: {
        accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
        secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_KEY,
      },
    });

    const ext = file.name.split(".").slice(-1)[0];
    const newFileName = uniqid() + "." + ext;

    const chunks = [];
    for await (const chunk of file.stream()) {
      chunks.push(chunk);
    }

    const buffer = Buffer.concat(chunks);
    const bucket = "doctors-kitchen";

    try {
      await s3Client.send(
        new PutObjectCommand({
          Bucket: bucket,
          Key: newFileName,
          ACL: "public-read",
          ContentType: file.type,
          Body: buffer,
        })
      );

      const link = "https://" + bucket + ".s3.amazonaws.com/" + newFileName;
      return Response.json(link);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error uploading to S3:", error);
      return Response.json(
        { error: "Failed to upload to S3" },
        { status: 500 }
      );
    }
  }

  console.log(data);
  return Response.json(true);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is telling you to use the regional endpoint for S3(and suggests `Endpoint: 'doctors-kitchen.s3.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com'` in the response). Insert the region into the S3 URL so instead of `[BUCKET_NAME].s3.amazonaws.com` you would use `[BUCKET_NAME].s3.[BUCKET_REGION].amazonaws.com`

Comment: When I use the following URL: s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com, I encounter the same error.

Comment: Ive updated my answer. Looking at your code again you do seem to have issues with the region. The response says the bucket is in `eu-north-1` but your S3Client is using `ap-south-1` and you need to include the correct region in the endpoint url as suggested. You can confirm the buckets correct region from the S3 console.

Comment: In my case the region is correct. I created the bucket in `eu-central-1` and I copied/pasted correctly, the error message still tell me to change to `eu-central-1`.

Comment: @SangDang - please create a new question that describes your issue and add the appropriate tags. Please do not reply to an already resolved question with a new question especially when not adding any useful information. If you have the exact same error as OP the chances are very high that you have some code (or config) issue